# How to use XPath to select Cartesian Product set of non null sibling nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, altova

First time poster here, so please don't hesitate to let me know if I've done something wrong.

I'm using Altova Stylevision to print out form documents, and I need to print a copy of the form for each unique set of two node collections.  Below is a sample XML to better explain what I'm asking for.

```
<form>
    <Animals>
        <Animal>
            <AName>Boomer</AName>
            <AAddress>House</AAddress>
        </Animal>
        <Animal>
            <AName>Growl</AName>
            <AAddress>Street</AAddress>
        </Animal>
        <Animal>
            <AName>Incognito</AName>
            <AAddress>Nowhere</AAddress>
        </Animal>
    </Animals>
    <People>
        <Person>
            <PName>Willy</PName>
            <PAddress>123 Common Lane</PAddress>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <PName>Wonka</PName>
            <PAddress>Chocolate Factory</PAddress>
        </Person>
    </People>
</form>
```

I'd like to produce 6 unique values (the Cartesian Product) from the above sample, containing every combination of `<Animal>` and `<Person>` where neither of them are null.  So, the output for this example would be like (just showing the grouping, need all child nodes instead of just names):

```
([Boomer, Willy], [Boomer, Wonka], [Growl, Willy], [Growl, Wonka], [Incognito, Willy], [Incognito, Wonka])
```

**EDIT:**  I'm trying to get the nodes, not just the `<Name>` element value.  Because I'm wrapping the whole StyleVision form in this template, the scope should be at the `<Animal>` and `<Person>` level.  This way, in the form I can just say `/AName, /PName,` and get one value for `/AName` and `/PName` on each copy of the form.  It should act as 6 instances of an element node, each one representing a unique combination of both `<Person>` and `<Animal>`.

I looked into the `for # in # return` syntax but I cannot figure out how to return the unique set.  Below is what I've tried so far:

```
for $a in form/Animals/Animal, $p in form/People/Person return ($a, $p)
```

and

```
form/Animals/Animal | form/People/Person
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Your `for` expression is correct, you just need to add an element constructor to get the result you need:

```
for $animal in $x/Animals/Animal,
    $person in $x/People/Person
return element union { $animal, $person }
```

The element name (`union` in the example) can be anything that you want.

---

*These original code samples will generate the result strings from the question.*

It's a little hard to read, but this will do what you want:

```
concat("(",
  concat(string-join(
    for $animal in /form/Animals/Animal/Name,
        $person in /form/People/Person/Name
    return concat("[", concat(string-join(($animal, $person), ", "), "]")), ", "), ")"))
```

If you can use an XPath/XQuery 3.0 processor, you can use the `||` concatenation operator instead of the `concat` function calls, which is (somewhat) more readable:

```
"(" ||
  string-join(
    for $animal in /form/Animals/Animal/Name,
        $person in /form/People/Person/Name
    return "[" || string-join(($animal, $person), ", ") || "]"
    , ", ")
|| ")"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I realize now that my question was poorly formed and I didn't really specify what I was looking for.  Instead of just string values, I'd like to take whole nodes.  I just remembered it's called **Cartesian Product**, and I'd like the product of the nodes to represent one overall product set.

Comment: Do you want the existing Animal and Person elements in a sequence, or do you want each union of an Animal and a Person inside of a new element?

Comment: The latter, each union of an Animal and a Person inside of a new element.  Your help is greatly appreciated!