# Nested For Expression and Relative Cartesian Products

Tags: for-loop, xpath, cartesian-product

I've seen that it's possible to do a [cartesian product in
XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687193/how-to-use-xpath-to-select-cartesian-product-set-of-non-null-sibling-nodes)
using a *For Expression*. For instance, given the following input:

```
<people>
    <group>
        <her>Alex</her>
        <him>Bert</him>
        <her>Cora</her>
        <him>Drew</him>
    </group>
    <group>
        <her>Edna</her>
        <him>Fred</him>
        <him>Gary</him>
    </group>
    <group>
        <her>Hope</her>
    </group>
</people>
```

I can pair every *her* with every *him* using:

```
for $her in /people/group/her, 
    $him in /people/group/him
return ($her/text(), $him/text())
```

Since both *binding sequences* share (unique) root, I thought that the
following expression should be equivalent to the previous one:

```
/people/(for $her in group/her, 
             $him in group/him 
         return ($her/text(), $him/text()))
```

Although this expression is parsed nicely, it produces (in my understanding) an unexpected result when executed on an [online
XPath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html). I've been
skimming the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-for-expressions)
and it seems that this expression shouldn't be valid.

Now, I'd like to be able to produce the cartesian product relative to a `<group>` tag. I mean, I'd like to do the cartesian product between *her*s and *him*s living in the very same group. If nested for expressions were viable, it should be something like this:

```
/people/group/(for $her in her, 
                   $him in him 
               return ($her/text(), $him/text()))
```

But again, this isn't producing the expected result.

Having said so, I have a few questions:

1. Is it valid to nest a for expression in a path? If so, why are the first and the second expressions producing different results?
2. If 1) isn't possible, what's the standard way of producing the cartesian
   product relative to the `<group>` tag?

Thank you!